# Sort DRF serializer output of nested Serializer field by child's field

Tags: django, sorting, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have two serializers, in which one refers to the other with a `many=True` relationship.

```
class AttributeInParentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    masterdata_type = CharField(max_length=256, source='masterdata_type_id')

    class Meta:
        model = Attribute
        fields = ('uuid', 'masterdata_type')

class ArticleInArticleSetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    attributes = AttributeInParentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('uuid', 'attributes')
```

The ordering of the attributes in the Article are not always the same, but I want to output them in the same order, so in this case ordering on the field `masterdata_type`. How can I accomplish this? Note that I do not want to change any client of the serializer if possible, and surely not any model.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Old thread, but because it's still popping up on Google I want to share my answer as well. Try overwriting the `Serializer.to_representation` method. Now you can basically do whatever you want, including customising the sorting of your response. In your case:

```
class ArticleInArticleSetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    attributes = AttributeInParentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('uuid', 'attributes')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        response["attributes"] = sorted(response["attributes"], key=lambda x: x["masterdata_type"])
        return response
```

Comment: I tried this in same scenario and its working. should be marked as accepted as it provides solution precisely as per question.

Answer (score 2):

you can set the ordering of attributes on ArticleInArticleSetSerializer by writing viewset for ArticleInArticleSetSerializer.

```
class ArticleInArticleSetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ArticleInArticleSetSerializer
    queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by('-attributes_id')
```

Or you can write a function for listing.

```
def list(self, request):
    self.queryset = self.get_queryset().order_by('-id')
    return super(yourViewSet, self).list(self, request)
```

This code only for reference

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This answer is a solution if the Serializer would be used in a view. However I am using the Serializer in another Serializer, and I want to fix this for all clients of the Serializer. So to be honest, I don't see how this answer would help.

Answer (score 2):

I found [an answer](https://tute.io/how-to-order-object-with-django-rest-frameworks-nested-serializer) I prefer over rewriting the `to_representation` method or doing an inline call to the `sorted` method (which loads all the instances in memory):

```py
class ArticleInArticleSetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    attributes = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_attributes_sorted')
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_attributes_sorted(instance):
        attributes = instance.attributes.order_by('masterdata_type')
        return AttributeInParentSerializer(attributes, many=True).data

    # Other stuff ...
```

This way you use a pure ORM solution (that's translated to SQL). The best performance and no memory consumption during sorting.

Comment: Does this solution makes extra query to the database? If there are a few elements to sort it might be faster to do this in memory rather than making an extra query to the database. As there is a database driver I/O overhead.

Comment: Hi @konstunn. Databases are made to receive queries all the time, trying to micro-optimize queries depending on the data size will result in a few ms time improvement but will make the code more unintelligible. A query to the DB is a few ms, for many as for few data this solution is good in performance and memory consumption

Answer (score -1):

You can't set the ordering on `ArticleInArticleSetSerializer` but you can set the ordering of `attributes` on `AttributeInParentSerializer`. This is because you can only set the ordering when you are consuming a serializer rather than when you're defining one.

You could perhaps set it in the `__init__` method when the queryset or data is passed in, but then you're making assumptions on what is being passed in. I'd probably end up specifying it in the consumers of `ArticleInArticleSetSerializer` to avoid any future problems with passing in a list to the serializer.

Comment: You're saying: you can set the ordering of `attributes` on `ArticleInArticleSetSerializer`. That is actually my exact question: how would I do so?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `order_by` inside of your serializer like this:

```
class AttributeInParentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    masterdata_type = CharField(max_length=256, source='masterdata_type_id')

    class Meta:
        model = Attribute
        fields = ('uuid', 'masterdata_type')
        order_by = (('masterdata_type',))
```

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE:**

Looks like I am mistaken. Could not find it from the documentation and it does not seem to work. Now, I don't think serializers are the place to do ordering. Best way to do is in the model or in the view.

Comment: Can you link to the docs that show the `order_by` attribute on a serializer's meta class? I can't find them and I can't get any ordering to work on a example snippet.

Comment: @schillingt Sorry, looks like I am mistaken. Please see my update

Comment: Ok, cool. We're on the same page then. Thank you for checking.